# Babel typescript preset not working together with react preset

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs

I am using the babel react preset to convert React components with JSX files into JS files. This works fine!

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react
```

Now I added the typescript preset,

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-typescript
```

Both presets are in .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/env", {"modules": false }],
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

I added the directories to tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "docs/js"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

But when I run Babel with

```
npx babel src --out-dir prod/js
```

The typescript preset is ignored. The react preset DOES work!

If I call the typescript preset manually in the terminal, it DOES work:

```
npx babel --presets @babel/preset-typescript src/test.ts
```

But now my React code is ignored.

How can I combine these two presets with Babel?

Comment: Does it help, if you pass the extensions as CLI arguments like `npx babel src --out-dir prod/js --extensions ".ts,.tsx"`?

Comment: Yes, that helps! It was a nightmare to figure this out. The babel website documentation is very sparse on this.